# When i insert value in the hire table it shows invalid identifier in the Vehicle_ID. There was no error while creating tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

```
-- Create a Database table to represent the "Vehicle" entity.
CREATE TABLE Vehicle(
    Vehicle_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Purchase_Date   DATE,
    Vehicle_No_Plate    VARCHAR(20),
    Brand                       VARCHAR(20),
    Vehicle_Type    VARCHAR(20),
    Model                       VARCHAR(20),
    Color                       VARCHAR(20),
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Vehicle".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT  pk_Vehicle PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);


-- Create a Database table to represent the "Hire" entity.
CREATE TABLE Hire(
    Hire_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Hire_Date   DATE,
    Drop_In_Day DATE,
    fk1_Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID),
    fk2_Vehicle_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Vehicle (Vehicle_ID) ,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Hire".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT  pk_Hire PRIMARY KEY (Hire_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Hire 
(Hire_ID, Hire_Date, Drop_In_Day, Customer_ID, Vehicle_ID)
 VALUES (10, '8/3/2017', '8/7/2017', 101, 112);
```

ORA-00904: "VEHICLE_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Did you use double quotes around the column name while creating the tables? A **quoted identifier** begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

Comment: - Create a Database table to represent the "Vehicle" entity.
CREATE TABLE Vehicle(
 Vehicle_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Purchase_Date DATE,
 Vehicle_No_Plate VARCHAR(20),
 Brand                     VARCHAR(20),
 Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(20),
 Model                     VARCHAR(20),
 Color                     VARCHAR(20),
 -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Vehicle".
 -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
 CONSTRAINT pk_Vehicle PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);    did this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Post the DDL for HIRE table. And please edit your question to post more details, not in comments. The more information you provide, the better answer you would get.

Comment: Your column is named `fk2_vehicle_id` in the table `hire`, not `vehicle_id`

Answer (score 1):

Try to examine this code snippet, it works for me.

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle( Vehicle_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                      Purchase_Date DATE,
                      Vehicle_No_Plate VARCHAR(20),
                      Brand VARCHAR(20), 
                      Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(20), 
                      Model VARCHAR(20), 
                      Color VARCHAR(20), 
                      CONSTRAINT pk_Vehicle PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID) ); 

CREATE TABLE Hire
(
  Hire_ID NUMBER,
  Hire_Date DATE,
  Drop_In_Day DATE, 
  Customer_ID NUMBER,
  Vehicle_ID NUMBER,

  CONSTRAINT vei FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_ID)
    REFERENCES Vehicle (Vehicle_ID),
  CONSTRAINT cust FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
    REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(Customer_id NUMBER, 
                      Name VARCHAR(20),
                      CONSTRAINT pk_Cust PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID));

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(100, 'Joe');

INSERT INTO vehicle VALUES(113, SYSDATE, 'PU-000-PU', 'FORD', null, null, null);

INSERT INTO Hire (Hire_ID, Hire_Date, Drop_In_Day, Customer_ID, Vehicle_ID)
 VALUES (10, '8/3/2017', '8/7/2017', 100, 112);
```

#### Edit

In your case the INSERT should look as follow if you want to keep the fk1_* naming.

```
INSERT INTO Hire 
(Hire_ID, Hire_Date, Drop_In_Day, fk1_Customer_ID, fk2_Vehicle_ID)
 VALUES (12, '8/3/2017', '8/7/2017', 101, 112);
```

The dates should work if the format fit your NLS_DATE_FORMAT but it is better to use the TO_DATE function.

Comment: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (C7202795.SYS_C00256461) violated - parent key not found ----- it shows this

Comment: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (C7202795.SYS_C00256461) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


1. INSERT INTO Hire 
2. (Hire_ID, Hire_Date, Drop_In_Day, fk1_Customer_ID, fk2_Vehicle_ID)
3.  VALUES (12, '8/3/2017', '8/7/2017', 101, 112);

Comment: Do you have a Customer with an ID of 101 and a Vehicle with the ID of 112?

Comment: Check the following link : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02291_integrity_constraint_string_string_violated_parent_key_not_found.htm

Comment: Yes I did Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The table DDL and INSERT statement posted by you are:

```
-- Create a Database table to represent the "Hire" entity.
CREATE TABLE Hire(
    Hire_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Hire_Date   DATE,
    Drop_In_Day DATE,
    fk1_Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID),
    fk2_Vehicle_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Vehicle (Vehicle_ID) ,
    -- Specify the PRIMARY KEY constraint for table "Hire".
    -- This indicates which attribute(s) uniquely identify each row of data.
    CONSTRAINT  pk_Hire PRIMARY KEY (Hire_ID)
);

INSERT INTO Hire 
(Hire_ID, Hire_Date, Drop_In_Day, Customer_ID, Vehicle_ID)
 VALUES (10, '8/3/2017', '8/7/2017', 101, 112);
```

These are couple of observations:

1. The column name "**Vehicle_ID**" used in `INSERT INTO Hire` statement doesn't exist in the HIRE table.

Your HIRE table should have the column to create the foreign key constraint to reference the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Hire
(
 Hire_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Hire_Date   DATE,
    Drop_In_Day DATE,
  Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Vehicle_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk1_Customer_ID  FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
    REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk2_Vehicle_ID   FOREIGN KEY (Vehicle_ID)
    REFERENCES Vehicle (Vehicle_ID)
);
```

So, you have Vehicle_ID column in HIRE table as foreign key referencing to Vehicle_ID column in VEHICLE table which is the primary key of that table. Same applies to Customer_ID.

2. '8/3/2017' is NOT a **DATE**, it is a **STRING**. Always use `TO_DATE` or ANSI DATE literal `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` to explicitly convert a string in to date.

For example:

```
TO_DATE('8/3/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

DATE '2017-03-08'
```

Comment: The 1. statement is also valid for the column fk1_Customer_ID since in the INSERT he uses the Customer_ID column name.

Comment: @dmak2709 Agreed, in fact there are many things missing. The column and constraint both are missing.

Comment: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (C7202795.FK2_VEHICLE_ID) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


1. INSERT INTO Hire 
2. (Hire_ID, Hire_Date, Drop_In_Day, Customer_ID, Vehicle_ID)
3.  VALUES (12, '8/3/2017', '8/7/2017', 101, 112);
it shows like this

Comment: @FluffyExcuse First you must insert data into parent tables customer and vehicle.